# How do I make a p5js drawing canvas only start after pressing button?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I currently have a p5js sketch that contains a button that says start drawing. I have it setup so that the drawing occurs while hovering over the canvas, however, I don't want this interaction to begin until after the user has pressed the button to start drawing. How should I go about making the drawing start only after the button is pressed.

```
var canvas;
var button;

function windowResized() {
    console.log('resized');
    resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}

function setup () {
    canvas = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    canvas.position(0,0);
    canvas.style('z-index', '-1')
    background(175);
    button = createButton("Start Your Drawing");
    button.mousePressed(draw);
}

function drawLine() {
    strokeWeight(4);
    line(pmouseX, pmouseY, mouseX, mouseY)
}

function draw () {
    // strokeWeight(4);
    // console.log('button')
    // line(pmouseX, pmouseY, mouseX, mouseY)
}
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always just give the illusion that the game is starting when you click "Start your drawing".

The setup function is called in p5.js first and only once, so let's write our code to define the canvas here. I've added a new `gameStarted` flag which is set to true when the player clicks the "Start your drawing" button. In the `draw()` we only set the canvas to the colour we want when the game has been started.

```js
let gameStarted = false;
function setup() {
    button = createButton("Start Your Drawing");
    button.mousePressed(() => gameStarted = true);
    canvas = createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    canvas.position(0,0);
    canvas.style('z-index', '-1')
    background(255);
}

function draw() {
  if (gameStarted) {
    background(220);
  }
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.2.0/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.2.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```